# swagger editor complains of Not a valid parameter definition

Tags: java, swagger

I am new to swagger. I have a swagger yaml

```
    /myApp/**:
get:
  tags:
    - myApp-controller
  summary: process a GET request for all URLs
  operationId: getRequestWithGhostURLsUsingGET
  produces:
    - application/vnd.api+json
  parameters:
    - name: multiParams
      in: query
      description: multiParams
      required: true
      items:
        type: object
        additionalProperties:
          type: string
```

It complains of error on  multiParams 
Details
 Object
code:  "ONE_OF_MISSING"
 params: Array [0]
message:  "Not a valid parameter definition"

Technically the method definition looks like this:

```
    @RequestMapping(value={"/**"},
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = {"application/vnd.api+json"} )
public MLRequest getRequestWithGhostURLs(HttpServletRequest request,
                                             @RequestParam MultiValueMap<String,String> multiParams){
}
```

I cant seem to find how can i describe multiValue request paramters.

Comment: Objects and hashmaps are not supported as query string parameters in OpenAPI/Swagger 2.0. Did you intend to pass the object in the body instead?

Comment: @Helen Thanks for the response. All request paramters/query paramters are strings. What i am intending to do is get all of them in a hashmap as I would not know what their names would be and how many would be there and process them from that map

Comment: 1) Which framework are you using? Springfox? 2) Hashmaps in query strings should be possible using OpenAPI 3.0 (at least, the Specification allows that) - but that comes down to whether your framework supports it. If it does not support OpenAPI 3 you'll probably have to pass the hashmap in the request body instead.

Comment: yes I am using Springfox, but the request parameter are themselves not Map they are coming as name value pairs but Spring allows me to get all of them in a hashMap which is the method signature. the method signatures ( i think) translates into the Swagger definition and vice versa. And you can see that that is not the case here. the method signature/spring makes all the query params in a map.

Comment: I also believe that i am using Swagger to define my code literally ( as it would need that to generate code) but I guess swagger is not supposed to do that rather it should give a very simple definition in a basic way and once the code is generated I can change the way i want it to be leaving the swagger definition as is.